# Move point to just before end of a comment

Tags: motion, comment, syntax-table

Given that the point is right in front of a comment, how do I move it to the end of the comment, but *before* the comment end markers?

For example:

- for a C++ `// xxx` comment, I would like to move the point to the end of the line
- for C-style `/* xxx */` comments I would like to move the point to right before the second `*`.

To complicate matters, I would like this to be mode independent. Also, I would like the solution to be based on the syntax table, as there are major modes that don't set up the comment-related regex variables properly.

Starting points:

- The function `forward-comment` can move the point the *after* the comment end marker, but I want it to stop before the comment end marker
- The syntax table can define three kinds of comments at the same time (where the `b` and `c` flags indicate that character is part of alternative comment kinds). When the point is inside a comment, the function `syntax-ppss` can tell which kind of comment it is.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done, although Emacs doesn't seem to provide useful info about multi-line comment ends, so it needs a hard coded check for `*/`.

```el
(defun my-end-of-comment ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((state (syntax-ppss))
        (point-init (point)))

    ;; We may be at the comment start, which isn't considered a comment.
    (unless (nth 4 state)
      (save-excursion
        (skip-syntax-forward "^-")
        (let ((state-test (syntax-ppss)))
          (when (and (nth 4 state-test) (<= point-init (nth 8 state-test)))
            (setq state state-test)))))

    (when (nth 4 state)
      (let ((start (nth 8 state)))
        (goto-char start)
        (forward-comment 1)
        (skip-syntax-backward ">")
        ;; Hard code '*/' for C.
        (when (looking-back "\\*\\/")
          (forward-char -2))))))
```

Comment: Close, but I would like to avoid hard-code things for a specific language. It fails for `// foo */`. This is a C++-style comment, but it place the point before  */. It also fails for `/*foobar*/` since the `(skip-syntax-forward "^-")` pass the entire comment. (The `(forward-char -3)` should be `(forward-char -2)`, since we can't assume that the `*/` sequence is preceded by a space, right?)

Comment: I don't think you can get this info - from the syntax tree at least.

I thought the `comment-end` or `block-comment-end` variables might be of use, but it seems neither are used by default.